# Enchanting the Wuuthrad

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In [this](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wuuthrad) link i came across the following statement

> You can add an enchantment to the Wuuthrad adding to its power. The
>   enchantment will not be listed; it will continue to say, "Especially
>   deadly to elves," it will, however, have the enchantment. Soul trap
>   (for instance) works; the charge level is available and applies to the
>   enchantment. (Not sure if this is a bug or purposely allowed.)

**Does this mean i can add any enchantment to the wuuthrad**? I did try.I recently purged the axe of burning and i have that enchantment but i am not able to use that enchantment on the wuuthrad.

Comment: as that is listed under "bugs", it's reasonable to assume that if you can't add an echantement to the item, the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can enchant the Wuuthrad. You can have any weapon based enchantments on it and you can alter the scale of the enchantment (you can have Fire at 3pts or 15pts, for example). Once you've enchanted the item, you enchantment is attached to that weapon, although it will still display the "deadly to elves" bonus as it's primary enchantment.